# Spring Boot Kafka Consumer to Repository Records

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a Spring Boot project that consumes kafka messages and has Repositories connected to a local instance of MYSQL.

My problem is that if I call my repository functions here to get fields from my DB. I get null pointer exceptions and found out that the Repositories returned null.

But I also have rest controllers and tried getting database data from there and the repositories work fine.

Is the problem because I can't call repository functions inside?

This is my Kafka Consumer.

```
@Component
 public class PromotionConsumer {

  @Autowired
  private ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;

  //Repositories
  private UserRepository User;
  private PromotionRepository Promotion;

  @KafkaListener(topics = "promotion")
  public void receive(ConsumerRecord<?,?> consumerRecord) {
    String kafkaRecommendationString = consumerRecord.value().toString();

    String recommendationString = (kafkaRecommendationString.substring(0,kafkaRecommendationString.length() - 1)).substring(1);
    String[] recommendationArray = recommendationString.split(",");

    Integer user_id = Integer.parseInt(recommendationArray[0]);
    Integer promotion_id = Integer.parseInt(recommendationArray[1]);

    //Repository Functions
    String first_name = User.findById(user_id).getfname();
    String last_name = User.findById(user_id).getlname();
    String promotion_name =Promotion.findById(promotion_id).getPromotionName();

    String final_recommendation = promotion_name+" is recommended for "+first_name+" "+last_name;
    producerTemplate.sendBody("direct:sendToMail", final_recommendation);
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't have `@Autowired` on your repositories

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Figured it out after i posted this. I thought @Autowired affects all underneath.